# I'm having trouble with moving a user that is already in a voice channel to another voice channel

Tags: discord.js

```
else if (command === 'move'){
        const member = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username == "0.o");
        const chan = client.channels.cache.get('761321016760336444');
        member.setVoiceChannel(chan);
```

Error
TypeError: member.setVoiceChannel is not a function
i've seen setVoiceChannel used before, not sure why it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using discord.js v12 you should do this instead

```js
member.voice.setChannel(chan);
```

you can read more about the voice state [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! with that code i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannel' of undefined" also sorry for the noob questions :D

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: i am on v12.18.4

Comment: then It might be a problem with finding the member, could you try finding it using the ID?

Comment: changing my code to this - "const member = client.users.cache.find(user => user.id == "259466508814516224");" gives me the correct member but also the same error